# MQ session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, messaging

I am trying to run my JMS session in CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode and if I am not acknowledging the message I am not seeing the message getting re-delivered to queue again, could you please let me know when the message will be delivered back to MQ, is it when the session terminates?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using`CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` in your receiver, then you must manually recover unacknowledged messages. Take a look at the JMS `Session.recover()` method, which will trigger the redelivery.

**References:**

- [Session.recover()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Session.html#recover%28%29)
- [JMS Specification 1.1 (p.66)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/docs-136352.html)